# Do I have to use a Git software or it's ok to use just the command line?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I always like the Command Line Environment because you feel like you have control on every thing. But is it necessary to use a software for using Git? How do companies handle this? Do they use CLI or do they use softwares?

Comment: Use whatever you are most comfortable with.

Comment: I've found that often, people who are less technical (but require access to the repo) or new to Git prefer GUIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it’s not necessary.

Since you are familiar with command line and like to use it, I will recommend you to use it directly.

Other IDE/software just operate based on git commands, and it’s limited for some commands to used in IDE. Such as `git filter-branch`, `git update-index` etc are not supported by most IDE (VS, TortoiseGit, sourceTree etc). It’s more free for you to use command line directly if you are used to it.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not necessary for obvious reasons. It's just a personal preference and you might find using a nice and tidy UI to be a lot more convenient, especially if you're new to the whole concept.

Behind the scenes pretty much any graphical user interface I know will just execute the actual command line tools so they don't have to reimplement everything in their own code.

So in the end, everyone runs the command line tools, even if they don't know it.

Personal opinion: If you're new and are just getting started, there's nothing wrong in using a graphical version to help you get along.

But once you know the basics, it won't hurt knowing the basics and how to do them on the command line:

- Initialize a new repository
- Clone an existing repository
- Push and pull changes
- Stage changes and commit them
- Create, switch, and delete branches
- Add, modify, and remove remotes

Once you know these, you should be able to handle your way around using command line only for pretty much all common tasks. You'll be a lot faster that way and it's a lot easier to automate things compared to a GUI client.

Answer (score 1):

From what I saw, it's a matter of taste to some companies. I've worked with 3 different companies with 3 different version controls: svn, git and tfvc and we did not use the CLI almost at all. It depends a lot on the company culture but from what I saw, the emphasis should be on knowing your tolling and being able to be productive with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to know the tool you chose.

I've seen companies that only works with CLI and others that also works with tools. Often, ... who only uses the tool, at some point do not know how to solve exceptions, conflicts, or something like that.

My suggestion is to learn the main tool (git). After that, just use the tool tailored on you. The purpose in your daily work is not to use a tool or another. The purpose is to create value and good software.

Comment: Yes, u right. I've improved my answer.